# How can I move around a circle and count the number of points inside it?

Tags: graphics

I have the following data:

```
data = {{223., 275.}, {212.5, 271.5}, {97.3889, 270.167}, {40., 269.}, {52.75, 266.875},{104.5, 265.5}, {241.7, 265.5}, {205.318, 263.318}, {217.045, 262.136}, {117.3, 257.5}, {69.2, 253.8}, {106.611, 253.833}, {198.389, 253.833}, {222., 254.}, {233.5, 254.}, {36.3889, 252.833},{210.214, 252.643}, {125.5, 250.5}, {92.5, 246.7}, {136.2, 246.8}, {115., 246.}, {147.682, 245.682}, {21.3, 244.5}, {104.5, 244.5}, {217.3, 244.5}, {244.3, 244.5}, {42.5, 242.3}, {72.8, 242.2}, {193.864, 241.955}, {31.8636, 240.955}, {123.1, 241.1}, {156., 241.}, {52., 240.}, {84.3889, 239.833}, {97.5, 237.5}, {142.786, 237.5}, {237.167, 237.611}, {64.5, 236.3}, {133.5, 236.5}, {109.045, 234.136}, {223.045, 234.136}, {34.4091, 232.864}, {77.3889, 232.833}, {117.318, 232.773}, {87.625, 231.625}, {151.3, 231.5}, {12.9545, 228.136}, {98.7, 228.}, {241.611, 225.833}, {139.5, 225.5}, {23.7, 224.5}, {81.1364, 223.409}, {171.3, 223.5}, {35.3889, 221.167}, {120.625, 221.375}, {158.2, 221.2}, {89.1364, 220.045}, {133.5, 217.5}, {147.7, 216.5}, {237.167, 216.611}, {110.167, 215.611}, {166.375, 215.375}, {177.167, 215.389}, {27.1364, 212.955}, {121.9, 211.9}, {38.8333, 210.611}, {92.5, 210.5}, {131.5, 208.3}, {158.056, 208.167}, {143., 207.3}, {19.0833, 204.75}, {72.5, 204.7}, {30.5, 203.5}, {171.167, 203.611}, {239.5, 203.5}, {252.3, 203.5}, {264.136, 203.591}, {84.7, 202.5}, {228.7, 202.5}, {42.3889, 199.833}, {123., 200.}, {51.6111, 198.833}, {76.3182, 196.682}, {64.5, 196.5}, {104.3, 195.5}, {144.167, 194.25}, {259.389, 194.167}, {34.1364, 191.955}, {235., 192.}, {114.833, 190.389}, {187.864, 190.591}, {56.5, 188.5}, {136.409, 188.318}, {158.3, 188.5}, {10.6111, 187.167}, {106.625, 183.625}, {139.409, 181.5}, {230.3, 182.5}, {47.2273, 181.318}, {90.3182, 181.318}, {59.8, 177.8}, {130., 178.}, {187.7, 178.}, {208.7, 175.5}, {81.1364, 174.409}, {139.5, 173.7}, {197.3, 173.5}, {241.833, 173.389}, {89.1154, 170.885}, {59.8, 167.2}, {175.625, 167.375}, {188., 166.}, {72.6111, 165.167}, {110.167, 165.056}, {159.611, 165.167}, {204., 165.}, {84.5, 161.5}, {143.136, 161.409}, {168.833, 161.389}, {262.7, 161.5}, {15.6111, 159.167}, {121.833, 159.389}, {102., 156.9}, {152.5, 157.}, {133.5, 154.5}, {75.0455, 153.136}, {113.625, 153.375}, {162.833, 153.389}, {85.5909, 152.136}, {241.611, 152.167}, {125.5, 149.7}, {96.3, 148.5}, {35.5, 146.5}, {105.5, 145.3}, {152.389, 145.167}, {197., 144.}, {85.7, 141.5}, {134.5, 141.5}, {162.833, 141.611}, {260.5, 141.5}, {175.833, 140.389}, {69.3889, 138.167}, {28.6429, 136.786}, {97.2, 136.8}, {129.167, 136.}, {39.625, 135.625}, {55.1667, 133.611}, {77.5, 133.5}, {164.3, 133.5}, {138.5, 132.5}, {213.5, 132.3}, {9.5, 131.}, {87.6111, 131.167}, {22.3889, 128.833}, {35.3889, 128.833}, {66.7, 128.5}, {177.136, 128.591}, {131.5, 125.3}, {189.722, 125.167}, {202., 125.}, {77.4091, 124.136}, {106.611, 123.833}, {160.611, 124.167}, {28.5, 122.7}, {142., 123.}, {214.5, 123.}, {226.5, 123.}, {15.5, 120.5}, {87.8333, 120.389}, {171.167, 120.611}, {5., 119.3}, {183., 117.}, {259.389, 117.167}, {73.1667, 115.583}, {98.6818, 115.682}, {131.318, 115.682}, {160.682, 114.682}, {34.1667, 114.611}, {193.7, 114.5}, {79.6667, 112.5}, {106.5, 112.5}, {203.786, 112.5}, {214.5, 112.5}, {13., 111.}, {59.3, 111.9}, {87.8636, 111.045}, {228.611, 111.167}, {69.3, 107.5}, {174.7, 107.5}, {151.3, 106.5}, {97.3889, 104.167}, {9.61111, 103.167}, {81., 103.}, {166.611, 103.167}, {61.2, 101.8}, {143., 102.}, {251.056, 101.833}, {71.5, 98.5}, {175.625, 98.375}, {238.167, 98.3889}, {90.3889, 95.8333}, {155.864, 95.9545}, {198.2, 94.9}, {138.375, 94.625}, {14.1667, 93.6111}, {59.8333, 93.6111}, {79.5, 93.5}, {112.682, 91.3182}, {33.875, 90.125}, {69.3182, 87.6818}, {150., 87.7}, {233.5, 87.5}, {180.5, 86.5}, {94., 85.3}, {190.167, 85.3889}, {242.833, 85.3889}, {19.1154, 82.8846}, {82., 83.}, {160.7, 83.}, {202., 83.}, {226.5, 79.7}, {129., 79.7}, {25.6818, 78.2273}, {39., 78.3}, {75.1364, 77.0455}, {48.1364, 74.9545}, {242.864, 74.9545}, {100.7, 73.5}, {120.5, 73.5}, {233.389, 73.1667}, {31.8333, 70.3889}, {69.2, 70.2}, {117.3, 65.5}, {226.5, 64.3}, {214.5, 62.}, {35.5, 60.7}, {205.3, 58.5}, {122., 57.3}, {180.375, 56.375}, {233.5, 56.3}, {43.5, 53.7}, {134.7, 54.}, {171.136, 53.9545}, {222.864, 53.9545}, {143.833, 49.0556}, {114.611, 47.8333}, {48.3, 45.5}, {81., 45.5}, {176., 45.5}, {40., 44.5}, {138.389, 40.8333}, {56.5, 39.7}, {127.239, 34.3261}, {67.0455, 32.8636}, {160.625, 32.625}, {118.5, 31.3}, {141.7, 31.5}, {55.0455, 29.1364}, {104.389, 28.1667}, {81., 26.7}, {93.7, 26.5}, {150., 26.7}, {110., 21.}};
```

which looks like:

```
p1 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Now, I need to draw a circle, let's say, with a radius $50$, centered at each of the above points step by step, and count the number points inside the circle. For example, for one of the above points as a center of the circle, one has:

```
p2 = Graphics[Circle[{79.66666666666667`, 112.5`}, 50]];
Show[p1, p2]
```

which looks like:

[image]

I can do the above repeatedly for other points as centers of the circle, and then count the number of points inside the circle at each step. However, this is very tedious and time-consuming.

I have the following two questions:

1. Is there an easier way to do the above procedure, and not manually do the counting and moving the circle around?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, I need also the circle to be remained completely inside the region of the points, that is, the center-points which result in a circle which some parts of it go outside the region, to be excluded (when doing by hand, one can detect these points. For example, one set of these points are those ones at the edges of the picture).

Comment: Part 2 can be rephrased: Is it possible for this circle to remain inside the convex hull established by the points?

Comment: @Syed Why convex? What if the boundaries are concave?

Comment: That's my best interpretation of "circle to remain completely inside the region...". I think that a convex hull would enclose a concave hull for the same set of points. If it is not true in general then can you please elaborate upon it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select subset of `data` that can be used as center of a disk given your second requirement:

```
r  = 50;

data2 = Select[RegionDistance[RegionBoundary[ConvexHullMesh[data]]]@# > r &]@data;
```

Associate with each element of `data2` a disk with radius `r` and the set of points from `data` that lie within that disk:

```
assoc = AssociationThread[data2, 
   {Tooltip[Disk[#, r], 
      Grid[{{"disk center:", #}, {"number of points:", Length@{##}}}, 
       Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {Left, Center}]], 
    Point @ {##2}} & @@@ Nearest[data, data2, {All, r}]];
```

Use `LocatorPane` to interactively select a disk using the element of `data2` closest to the locator:

```
NF = Nearest[data2];

DynamicModule[{pt = Mean[data]}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
  Dynamic @ Graphics[{
      Point @ data, 
      Green, PointSize[Medium], Point @ data2,
      PointSize[Large], Red, Point @ NF @ pt, 
      PointSize[Medium], Blue, EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Opacity[.3, Red]], 
        assoc @ First[NF @ pt]}, 
    PlotRange -> (MinMax /@ Transpose[data]), 
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) to retrieve all points from a dataset that are within radius `r` of a chosen point. First, construct the "nearest function",

```
nf = Nearest[pts]
```

Then to get all points within radius `r` of `pt`, you can use `nf[pt, {All, r}]`.

Comment: @Eternity It is not clear to me _where_ you want to move the circle to (other than that you want to keep it within a certain region). It is also unclear which specific region you want to restrict it to. One comment said convex hull. What if the points are in a highly non-convex region?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to locate points, and bounding regions for the data. A circle at a point in the red area would include parts outside the `br` bounding region.

```
r = 50; (* choose a radius *)
nf = Nearest[data];
br = BoundingRegion[data, "MinDisk"];
c = RegionCentroid[br];
br2 = Disk[c, br[[2]] - r];

Show[Region[Style[br, Red]], Region[br2], 
 Epilog -> {Black, Point[data]}]
```

[image: bounding region]

We can find all the center-points which result in circles which remain inside the `br` region. Let's use one of these points to demonstrate how to find points within a circle with radius `r`.

```
testPoints = nf[c, {All, br2[[2]]}];
SeedRandom[123];
pt = RandomChoice[testPoints]; (* one of the testPoints *)
pts = nf[pt, {All, r}];
Show[Region[Style[RegionBoundary[br], Red]], Region[Disk[pt, r]], 
 Epilog -> {Black, Point[pts]}]
Length[pts]
```

[image: selected points]

```
(* 41 *)
```

Find points within radius `r` for all the `testPoints`:

```
nf[#, {All, r}] &@ testPoints
```